# Angular Scope issue -> function comes off scope after one use?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
  $scope.newLike = LikeFactory.newLike;
  $scope.newDislike = LikeFactory.newDislike;
  $scope.updateLike = LikeFactory.updateLike;
  $scope.updateDislike = LikeFactory.updateDislike;

  $scope.vote = function(sockId, nnew, update) {
    if (!$scope.verifyUser) $scope.alert("Please log in to like a sock!");

    if (!$scope.like.like && !$scope.like.dislike) {
      return nnew(sockId).then(function(vote) { $scope.vote = vote; });
    } else {
      return update(sockId).then(function(update) { $scope.vote = update; });
    }
  }
```

I call this function, $scope.vote, in the html with an ng-click="vote(sock.id, newLike, updateLike)" or ng-click="vote(sock.id, newDisike, updateDislike)" whether on an like vs dislike button. The call button works fine when first liking and updating once there is an instance of a 'like' for a particular unique sock/user combo but after one 'update' I get the error:

```
angular.js:13642 TypeError: v2.vote is not a function
```

Do I need to trigger a $digest for the function to continue to be in $scope? Does it somehow come off $scope after being used? It seems like a strange error to me.

Edit: duh! It's late, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

You define `$scope.vote` as a function in your controller. After first invocation you assign a result that may not be a function to this variable, thus `vote` is no longer a function:

```
$scope.vote = function() {} // => 'vote' variable is holding a function

$scope.vote = vote / update // => 'vote' might not reference a function but a value
```

Log your result after the promise is resolved (in the `then` block), to understand what is the new assigned value.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal, here : `$scope.vote = update` you use the same varaible that the function name

Answer (score 1):

The issue must be with the following statement:

```
$scope.vote = vote;
```

The `vote` might not be function and so `v2.vote is not a function`